# Require Specific First Characters from Form Post

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, input

I'm just putting this out there to see if anyone can catch my drift and give a hand..
I work for a public library and am in the process of making a "Self Checkin" machine.
Here's some code from it - There's a form called "checkin" with an input called "barcode" - the result of "barcode" is posted to a php file which the sends the data to the Library System and receives a message which is then passed into a table "completed-checkins".

It's all working fine but - I need to put some conditions on what data is accepted from the form.. The conditions are the first two characters need to be t00 .

I've been searching the web and trying to borrow/adapt code from others to make this work, which is where i got this from;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkCode() {
        var form = document.getElementById('checkin');
        var x = form.elements.barcode.value.substring(0, 2);
        //  var x = this.value.substring(0, 2);
        if (x == 't00') document.getElementById('#barcode').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

I'm no real coder but am wondering if anyone who is can see how I could get this to work? (it doesn't at the moment).

Thanks much for looking,

Jordan.

And here's the html with all the scripts;

```
<body OnLoad="$('#barcode').focus();" style="padding:40px;">
    <center>
        <p>
            <img src="selfchecklogo.png" />
        </p>
        <div class="formbarwrapper">
            <div class="formbar">
                <form method="post" name="checkin" id="checkin" onsubmit="return checkCode()" />
                <input name="barcode" id="barcode" placeholder="scan an item..." autocomplete="off" maxlength="9" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="result">
            <table id="completed-checkins">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="cell"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkCode() {
        var form = document.getElementById('checkin');
        var x = form.elements.barcode.value.substring(0, 2);
        //  var x = this.value.substring(0, 2);
        if (x == 't00') document.getElementById('#barcode').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#checkin').submit(function() {
            $.post("index.php", {
                barcode: $('#barcode').val()
            },

            function(data) {
                var content = '';
                content += '<div class="result">';
                content += '<tbody>';
                content += '<tr>';
                content += '<td>' + data + '</td>';
                content += '</tr>';
                content += '</tbody>';
                content += '</div>';
                $('#barcode').val('').focus();
                $('#completed-checkins tbody').html(content);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried printing "x" to the console?  I think your problem is that this line

```
var x = form.elements.barcode.value.substring(0, 2);
```

only selects the first two characters out of the string, and then you compare it to "t00", which is three characters long and thus will always evaluate to false.

Also, you might want to consider using the "===" operator instead of the "==" operator.  In this case both would work, but using "===" is a good habit to get in to.  "===" works the way you expect it to work, whereas "==" has some little gotchas in Javascript.  For instance

```
0 == '0' //This evaluates to true
0 === '0' //This evaluates to false
```

Basically, "==" doesn't check for type, and "===" does.